# Grouping each 500 elements of array according to array elements

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have an array of 2000 strings. The strings are: "art", "economy", "sport" and "politic". I want to group each 500 elements and get their counts

Could anyone help please?

Comment: What's wrong with simply looping over them, checking which string it is and increasing the correct counter?

Comment: Gaminic, I would like to use groupby please ... thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution:

```
var count = 0;
var dictionaries = 
    strings.GroupBy(s => count++ / 500)
           .Select(g => g.Distinct().ToDictionary(k => k, k => g.Count(s => s == k)))
           .ToList();
```

This will create a `List<Dictionary<string, int>>`. Each dictionary represents a tally of 500 elements (or possibly less for the last dictionary), where the keys are strings and the values are the number of occurrences of the string among the 500 elements the dictionary represents.

There is no requirement to hardcode all the possible values that may be encountered.

For the maximum possible performance you can also use this version:

```
var count = 0;
var dictionaries = 
    strings.GroupBy(s => count++ / 500)
           .Select(g => g.Aggregate(
               new Dictionary<string, int>(), 
               (d, w) => { d[w] = (d.ContainsKey(w) ? d[w] + 1 : 1); return d; })
           )
           .ToList();
```

This version iterates over each element in your source array exactly once. The output is in the same format as the first version.

Comment: Please, I want to get the following output 
art = 125
economy = 100
politic = 75
sport = 200

per each 500 ... i.e. 4 times

Comment: @Jon neat solution, quick typo `count++ / 3` -> `count== / 500`

Comment: Does this code gives me 4 dictionaries located in the list and each dictionary has 4 pairs (each string with  its count )  ???

Comment: @Qaesar assuming your list of strings contains 4 distinct strings and is 2000 entries long then yes. Though note you need to update the `count++` statement so it groups by `500` not by `3`...

Comment: @user1793607: Thanks, copy/paste error (I did a test run with just a few elements).

Comment: @Qaesar: The answer explains exactly what the output is -- does it need more clarification? Please be aware that you are supposed to make some effort to understand how an answer works. Noone is interested in doing consulting work for free.

Comment: @ Jon, i have tried your code but it showed an overload error at the line "d[w] = (d.ContainsKey(w) ? d[w]" !!! could you help me please ?

Comment: @Qaesar: Definitely not without the full error message. The code works with .NET 4 -- what version are you on?

Comment: Ok. it has done with the first version . thank you. please adjust the second one for others who want to get benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var grouping = Enumerable.Range(0,2000)
                       .Select(i => i / 500)
                       .Zip(Strings, (i,s) => new { Group = i, Str = s})
                       .GroupBy(anon => anon.Group,
                                anon => anon.Str,
                                (key,g) => new
                                           {
                                             Key = key,
                                             Art = g.Count(str => str == "art"),
                                             Economy = g.Count(str => str == "economy"),
                                             Politic = g.Count(str => str == "politic"),
                                             Sport= g.Count(str => str == "sport")
                                           });

foreach(anon in grouping)
{
    //textbox logic OP will have to change to suit
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Group: {0}", anon.Key));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Art: {0}",anon.Art));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Economy: {0}",anon.Economy ));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Politic: {0}",anon.Politic ));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Sport: {0}",anon.Sport));
}
```

Alternatively (as per Snowbear)

```
var grouping = Strings.Select((s,i) => new { Group = i / 500, Str = s})
                      .GroupBy(anon => anon.Group,
                               anon => anon.Str,
                               (key,g) => new
                                 {
                                  Key = key,
                                  Art = g.Count(str => str == "art"),
                                  Economy = g.Count(str => str == "economy"),
                                  Politic = g.Count(str => str == "politic"),
                                  Sport= g.Count(str => str == "sport")
                                 });

foreach(anon in grouping)
{
    //textbox logic OP will have to change to suit
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Group: {0}",anon.Key + 1));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Art: {0}",anon.Art));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Economy: {0}",anon.Economy ));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Politic: {0}",anon.Politic ));
    TextBox1.WriteLine(String.Format("Sport: {0}",anon.Sport));
}
```

Comment: There's no need in `Enumerable.Range`. `Select` method has an overload which provides index so you can write: `Strings.Select((s,i) => new { ... })` directly.

Comment: @Snowbear true, have edited to include the select version, I just prefer being more explicit. I would assume implementation for known fixed size should be identical, but the select method would be better for unknown size.

Comment: I just want to know, this code works for only first 500 or for the whole array. because i want to write the counts for each Art,Economy, Politic and sport per each 500 elements..

Comment: @Qaesar Will work for the whole array, but you should have a look at Jons solution below, is very neat.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = strings.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.i / 500)
                .Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.s)
                                .Select(z => new { 
                                                    Name=z.Key,
                                                    Count=z.Count()
                                                }).ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int CountElementsInGroup = 500;
//from 500 to 1000
int NumberGroup = 2;
string[] GroupTypes = new string[4] { "art", "economy", "sport", "politic" };

//Fill example array
string[] arr = new string[2000];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length;i++ )
    arr[i] = GroupTypes[rand.Next(0, 3)];
    var res = (from p in arr.Skip((NumberGroup - 1) * CountElementsInGroup).Take(CountElementsInGroup)
              group p by p into g
              select new GroupCountClass { GroupName = g.Key, GroupCount = g.Count() });

textBox1.Text = "";
foreach (GroupCountClass c in res)
{
   textBox1.Text += String.Format("GroupName:{0} Count:{1};",c.GroupName,c.GroupCount);
}
```